# Determine what port OpenSUSE firewall is blocking

Tags: opensuse, firewall, ftp

I am having a problem with the WebStorm IDE in that I cannot use its built-in FTP capabilities probably due to my OpenSUSE (Tumbleweed) firewall blocking some needed ports. I am assuming that because after turning off the firewall it suddenly works. My problem is that I have no idea what port(s) I need to open because plain ftp from both Firefox and Nautilus work without problems and I am guessing that WebStorm using some other extra protocols. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to determine what they might be. I have told YaST to log all not-accepted packets but using sudo SuSEfirewall2 log gives the following error:

```
Can't open /var/log/firewall: No such file or directory at /etc/sysconfig/scripts/SuSEfirewall2-showlog line 67.
```

I can confirm that the file does indeed not seem to exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

FTP works on ports 20/21; however, this shouldn't be a problem for you as a **client**.

If you are a **server** and a client can't get to you then you need to open those ports through `yast`.

Run `yast firewall` as root and then go to allowed services, advanced, and then add in the ports.

If you *really* want to you can use `iptables`, but the rules on OpenSuSE are a real pain in the butt and **everyone** mentions that you should just use YaST.

Of course, be aware that any passwords are sent across as plain text.

Finally, for your file not found error: `touch /var/log/firewall`

Answer (score 0):

The message for the rejection may be hitting your syslog, which you can see at `/var/log/messages` or by using `journalctl` depending on your version of OpenSuSE.

A key point to make here is that the firewall can block both incoming and outgoing ports, which potentially include the ephemeral ports that you (as the FTP client) need to have opened for outgoing traffic. I must say it's unusual to have outgoing ephemeral ports blocked, but it's not impossible.

Despite that it's unpleasant, maybe try dumping the iptables rules and dig into them.